# Are headers, footers, sidebars Django Apps?

Tags: django, django-apps

Is the header, footer, sidebar  of a website separate applications in a django project?

Comment: I wouldn't have them separate, but I guess you could if you really wanted to. not sure why you would.. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I completed 10 apps for my website, now to put them together as elements of my website I will need menus to call those apps, i'm wondering how to do this the Dnago way?

Comment: You should edit your question to explain what you're doing.

Comment: Django experts will know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

No, they usually aren't. Usually header, footer, sidebar of a website are separete [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/) that fit together using django's template engine.

Comment: Sometimes I put the the views and templates associated specifically with navigation and index pages in an app dedicated to this purpose, so that I know right where to find them and so that I could delete an app and not lose the navigation logic.